# How to add player name in action script 3

Tags: android

i want to make a game that
when some one write his/her name in a text input it shows in next frame:"Welcome(player name)to the game

What should i do now?

Help me please as much as u can.
Thank U.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in SharedPreference and use it wherever you want to use it.
take a look at this :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Simple example code :

```
//save player name
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("name", "player name");
editor.commit();

//fetch name
sharedpreferences.getString("name","defaultName");
```